# How can I remove keyboard focus from a button on User Control after clicking it, in a vb.net PowerPoint add-in?

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, focus, powerpoint, add-in

I have a vsto add-in for PowerPoint (vb.net) which includes a User Control with several buttons.

After clicking any of those buttons, or the User Control itself, I can't immediately use 'Ctrl' keyboard shortcuts, like Ctrl+C. It seems that the button or the User Control gets the focus. If I click on the slide, 'Ctrl' keyboard shortcuts work again.

Is there a way that I can take the focus away from the Button / User Control, in my Button1.Click event handler, in order to be able to use Ctrl+C right away? Or a way in which I can place the focus on the PPT Presentation?

I have searched and tried a ton of different methods, with no success...

PS: One observation I have made is that if instead of a Button, I click a Panel within my User Control, I do not have this problem.
Another observation is that while I can't use 'Ctrl' shortcuts right after clicking the button, 'Alt' shortcuts continue working fine.

Comment: By "User Control", do you mean a VBA UserForm? If so, have you looked at modifying the Fluent UI (also called Ribbon UI) to add your controls to the PowerPoint Ribbon?

Comment: My add-in has both a custom Ribbon tab and a User Control, which is essentially a task pane on the right side of the screen w/ buttons.

Meanwhile, I found this link which gives a solution in C# that I have managed to successfully convert to vb.net and implement in my program: https://blog.tombam.net/an-unselectable-usercontrol/

Now, if I click the User Control, it doesn't receive focus and I can continue using Ctrl shortcuts. However, if I click a button in the User Control, I still have the same problem. So the issue remains: I need to prevent those buttons from getting keyboard focus.

Comment: I just found a solution for the buttons: declaring a new class of buttons which inherits button but sets Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, False).

Public Class NoFocusButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Sub New()
        Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, False)
    End Sub
End Class

Thank you, this is solved.